# Amazon CloudWatch Metric Math - Rolling Average

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

So I am trying to visualize a AWS CloudWatch Metric with Tolerance via AWS Managed Grafana.

For example, this is my current graph (and I want to add tolerance lines to it):

[image]

I want to add some tolerance lines too see which spikes go outside of the expected range.

I could technically do this by enabling [CloudWatch anomaly detection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Anomaly_Detection.html) and using `ANOMALY_DETECTION_BAND(a)` as my metric math but I am trying to replicate a dashboard we currently have which uses a *6 week rolling average* with a simple multiplier as the upper and lower thresholds.

My thought was that I can accomplish this [using metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html)  by leveraging a combination of `SLICE`, `RUNNING_SUM`, and `DATAPOINT_COUNT` but no matter what combination I try I can't seem to find the right mix.

Does anyone know how I can using Metric Math to create a time series where each data point is either:

- The average of the last `x` amount of time data points (Ex: the last 6 days worth of data points)
- The average of the last `x` data points.

If I can figure out either of these solutions I can do the rest but I am having a hard time just getting "the last `x` data points" instead of referencing the entire query when doing any metric math operation.

I could maybe find a way to do this with built in Grafana functionality as well but I couldn't find a great way to do it. (Still new to Grafana).